# Itunes Connect - Cannot submit In-App Purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I created an application for submission in Itunes Connect and assigned some in-app purchases to the application. I sent it for review and it was rejected. I got the reasons why it was rejected and also the following:

`We have returned your IAP product/s to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the IAPs with the binary.`

Now when I go to the Application Details page, I can edit the meta-data and screenshots and so on, but I find no way where to assign the in-app items to the application.

Any help?

Comment: Did you find the answer? because I am facing same problem

Comment: @BhaveshLathigara Nope.

Answer (score 1):

This was useful for me:

[Escaping iTunes Connect App Submission Rejected-Ready-Waiting Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171822/escaping-itunes-connect-app-submission-rejected-ready-waiting-loop)

Have to re-submit your app then go into the in-app purchase section and edit the language settings.