# How to create a "Build" record in iTunesConnect using a list lacking today's build?

Tags: ios, app-store

## Problem

Apparently iTunesConnect wants me to create a "Build" record by choosing recent build, but today's build does not appear.

## Details

First I choose `Product` > `Build` in Xcode 5.1.1.

I go to the iTunesConnect page under "MyApps", with the tabs across the top: `Versions`, `Prerelease`, `In-App Purchases`, `Game Center`, `Reviews`, `Newsstand`, `More`.

I manually update the version number in the "Version" field to match the project settings value in Xcode 5.1.1.

I return to the Organizer in Xcode. I click the "Validate" button, and wait for the no-problems message. Then I click the "Distribute" button and follow steps for uploading to App Store Review. Wait for upload to Apple finish, when Organizer shows status as "Submitted".

Back to iTunesConnect. Scroll down to `Build` list (now empty). Click the "+" button. A dialog appears with a bullet list showing only the previous build. Today's new build is not in the list.

What to do next?

Adding this "Build" record seems to be necessary. If I click the `Submit for Review` button at the top of the iTunesConnect page, I get the error message `ITC.apps.validation.prerelease_build_missing`. According to lore that means I need to add this "Build" record on the same page to make Apple happy.

Why is this so complicated? If my app successfully uploaded to the App Store from Xcode, why am I noodling around with this iTunesConnect page? What more do I have to do to get this app submitted? I've submitted this app in the past, so I'm mystified as to what has changed and what I need to do now.

If I need to create a "Build" record on the iTunesConnect page, how do I do that in the presented dialog box listing builds yet lacking today's fresh build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Wait.

Really, that's the answer: **Wait**.

After uploading your fresh binary in Xcode 5, it may take a long while for Apple's backend servers to sync up and become informed about the new arrival. By "long while", perhaps the half hour or hour or more I spent grappling with this problem, googling, reading, and finally authoring this Question.

Eventually I went back to iTunesConnect, clicked the "+" button in the "Builds" area of the page, a dialog appeared showing two radio buttons rather than the single one seen earlier, for the old upload as well as today's fresh upload.

## Steps To Success

These are the steps that seem to have worked for me.

1. Build "Archive" in Xcode.
2. Copy version number to new build record in "My Apps" in iTunesConnect. (To avoid warning in next step)
   [a] From the Organizer, copy the version number of your app (I'm assuming you have a script to auto-generate the number).
   [b] Click the big button in upper right, something like "New Release", to create a new record in their system. The new record looks something like a tab near the top of this page.
   [c] Paste the version number into a dialog box that appears. Or after the full page appears, find the Version field in lower left of this page (scroll down), and [d] If available, click the big "Save" button in upper-right to post the current values in this page to Apple’s servers.
3. Validate in Xcode Organizer.
   I assume you already prepared a provisioning profile for the App Store. Be sure to choose the correct profile, not the Ad Hoc one you created for use with the TestFlightApp.com system.
4. Distribute in Xcode Organizer. (Uploads to Apple)
   Logic might suggest that you are done, but No, much more to do.
5. If you have In-App Purchase products, click that tab to review their status.
   Apple has a goofy fragile system that may inactivate your products, displaying their Language entries with a yellow background. If so, open each Language entry, perform any edit (even adding an extra SPACE), and click the now-enabled Save button. Click appropriate buttons to save your changes and return to main "My Apps" page for your app.
6. **Take a break**, walk the dog, do some stretching, eat an orange, read [MacNN](http://www.macnn.com) and [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk).
7. In iTunesConnect "My Apps" page, click the "+" button in the "Builds" lower portion of the page.
   A dialog appears listing recent builds uploaded. If your fresh build is not yet listed, go read a [John Siracusa](http://arstechnica.com/author/john-siracusa/) article in Ars Technica. Come back afterwards, and try this step again.
8. Choose your fresh build in the dialog, and complete adding the "Build" record.
9. Click the "Save" button at the top of the page to save the Build record.
   Note how the disabled "Submit For Review" neighboring button becomes available.
10. Click the `Submit For Review` button.
    The buttons disappear, and your app is apparently submitted for review. Unfortunately Apple does nothing to confirm that fact. I know of no way to confirm that your submission in complete and successful. You may or may not receive a confusing "In Review" message from Apple but until days later, or you may not receive any acknowledgment at all.

---

I am not sure of the exact button and headings captions mentioned above. Use your smarts to translate my vague memories. I will update this info on my next submission attempt.

Comment: ahhah the solution is ... WAIT ! You are totally right. It took about 1 hour for me, my dog has been very tired to walk ...